# Magento add submenu in customer dashboard left navigation

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have added my custom menu in left navigation of customer dashboard page but i also want to add sub-menu to my custom menu.

Is there any way to add sub-menu ?

I have created menu using below code

```
<customer_account> 
  <reference name="customer_account_navigation"> 
    <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>billing_agreements</name></action>           
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="test">
      <name>info_edit</name>
      <path>test/index/getinfo/</path>
      <label>Custom menu</label>
    </action>                   
 </reference> 
</customer_account>
```